# Color of pheomelanin?

Tags: physical-chemistry, color

Do we know what is the wavelength of the color of [pheomelanin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melanin#Pheomelanin)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pheomelanin has a very broad absorption spectrum in the visible, with monotonically increasing absorption as the wavelength decreases until a maximum is reached at 300 nm.

I think that this would correspond to a dark red/brown colour.

Source: [*Phys. Chem. Chem. Phys.* **2011,** *13* (20), 9119–9127](https://doi.org/10.1039/C1CP20131J)